# Monotouch Linea Pro SDK issue with build arguments

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, linea-pro

Hopefully someone can help me or point me in the right direction. I am using monotouch to write an iPod Touch app that uses the Linea Pro barcode scanner case.

I have the SDK for the Linea Pro case and I've followed the following tutorial

http://blog.davidsandor.com/post/2011/01/05/iPhone-iTouch-barcode-scanning-Hello-World-application-with-MonoTouch-and-LineaSDK.aspx

(you can see I've posted a response asking for help but I'm a little confused by the "non-thumb" build)

I have tried matching the suggested versions of montouch etc but cannot find monotouch 3.2.4

The issue i am having is when i enter the arguments in to the build options the app launches and crashes straight away, if i remove the build arguments the app launches fine but the linea pro case will not work (as you would expect)

the build argument I'm using is

```
-v -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lLineaSDK -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework ExternalAccessory -ObjC"
```

if I try and build it via the simulator i get the follow

> Error 1: mtouch failed with the following message:
>   /var/folders/0q/kc6tw0jd35n7nsc4fmt98yvm0000gn/T/tmp140720c3.tmp/main.m:
>   In function 'main':
>   /var/folders/0q/kc6tw0jd35n7nsc4fmt98yvm0000gn/T/tmp140720c3.tmp/main.m:1838:
>   warning: implicit declaration of function
>   'monotouch_enable_debug_tracking'
>   /var/folders/0q/kc6tw0jd35n7nsc4fmt98yvm0000gn/T/tmp140720c3.tmp/main.m:1921:
>   warning: implicit declaration of function 'mini_get_debug_options'
>   /var/folders/0q/kc6tw0jd35n7nsc4fmt98yvm0000gn/T/tmp140720c3.tmp/main.m:1925:
>   warning: implicit declaration of function
>   'mono_debugger_agent_parse_options'
>   /var/folders/0q/kc6tw0jd35n7nsc4fmt98yvm0000gn/T/tmp140720c3.tmp/main.m:2058:
>   warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
>   /var/folders/0q/kc6tw0jd35n7nsc4fmt98yvm0000gn/T/tmp140720c3.tmp/main.m:2058:
>   warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
>   Undefined symbols:   "__Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow", referenced from:
>         -[CommStream readThread:] in libLineaSDK.a(CommStream.o)
>         -[CommStream stream:handleEvent:] in libLineaSDK.a(CommStream.o)
>         -[EAStream eaClean] in libLineaSDK.a(EAStream.o)
>         -[EAStream EAAccessoryDidConnect:] in libLineaSDK.a(EAStream.o)
>         -[Linea paperStatus:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea magneticCardData:track2:track3:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea smartCardRemoved] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea smartCardInserted] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea barcodeData:type:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea btmSetEnabled:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea btmGetEnabled] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea bt301ReadThread:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea cryptoAuthenticateiPod:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea setBarcodeTypeMode:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea getBarcodeTypeMode] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea msProcessFinancialCard:track1:track2:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea updateFirmware:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea playSound:beepData:length:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea setScanBeep:volume:beepData:length:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea processData:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea sendCommand:command:inData:inLength:outData:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea setConnState:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea processBTEvents:] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Linea dealloc] in libLineaSDK.a(LineaSDK.o)
>         -[Printer msProcessFinancialCard:track1:track2:] in libLineaSDK.a(PrinterSDK.o)
>         -[Printer cryptoRawSetKey:encryptedData:] in libLineaSDK.a(PrinterSDK.o)
>         -[Printer closeChannel:] in libLineaSDK.a(PrinterSDK.o)
>         -[Printer openChannel:] in libLineaSDK.a(PrinterSDK.o)
>         -[Printer flushCache] in libLineaSDK.a(PrinterSDK.o)
>         -[Printer initCheck] in libLineaSDK.a(PrinterSDK.o)
>         -[Printer processData:] in libLineaSDK.a(PrinterSDK.o)
>         -[Printer setConnState:] in libLineaSDK.a(PrinterSDK.o) ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  (1) (SwipeIT)

Can anyone help me out in anyway or point me in the right direction? any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did it work or did you give up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow is a C++ symbol [1] so you should add a "--cxx" option to the one you are already providing.

This will switch from gcc (C) to g++ (C++) compilers/linkers and should provide the library with the missing symbols.

[1] http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib--unwind-resume-or-rethrow.html